# How can I find the encryption/encoding method used on a file given its original version

Tags: image, image-processing, encryption, encoding

I have two image files. One is a regular picture [[here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60802960/IMG_0886%20-%20Copy.JPG)], while the other is it's foreignly modified counterpart retrieved from a remote server [[here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60802960/test2.jpg)]. I have no idea what the server did to this image or the rest of them stored on the server, but they are obviously modified in some way because the second file cannot be read. They are both the exact same picture, even the same byte count, but I can't figure out how to reverse whatever was done. What should I be trying?

Note: The modified file was retrieved from a packet capture as an octet stream. I wrote the raw binary to a file and then base64 decoded it.

Comment: First 'here' lined to "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60802960/IMG_0886%20-%20Copy.JPG", and second 'here' linked to html file which contains img tag with src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60802960/test2.img".  Two URL's are different, and second URL is invalid (404 error) . Why are you sure that they are the exact same picture?

Comment: @Fumu7 I just fixed the links; thanks for the heads up. Also, I am sure they are the same picture because I put the picture on the server.

Comment: Well, the first is a photo taken near Lafayette, and the second... isn't! The files are the same length, yes. The second one is not the first one reversed, and the mapping from the first to the second is non-trivial because repeated bytes in the first do not come out the same every time in the second. The header bytes are not recognised by the `file` command. Not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the original JPEG file, the encrypted data is very "random" — every byte value from 0 to 255 appears with almost exactly the same probability. This rules out the possibility of a [transposition cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher).

Also, the files are exactly the same length (3,018,705 bytes), which makes it unlikely that a [block cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) (like [DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard)) was used.

So that makes a stream cipher (like [RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4)) the most likely candidate. If this is the case, you can obtain the keystream simply by XORing each byte of the two files together. However, you might find it difficult to figure out the cryptographic key from this data. Good luck with that :-)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. If I just wanted to be able to decrypt the rest of the pictures on the server, would obtaining the keystream be enough? Also, would it help to have more samples from the same server? Thanks again.

Comment: I just XORed the two files and it didn't give me anything useful

Comment: @Garrett Well, *if* this is indeed RC4 encryption (not unlikely) and *if* the exact same key is used for every file (exceedingly unlikely) then yes, you could just XOR the same keystream with the contents of all the other files to retrieve the original data. But if you obtained this data by fetching packets from encrypted HTTP traffic, then each file would either be sent using a different cryptographic key, or using a different part of the same keystream. Either way, you're going to find it very difficult to recover anything.

Comment: I was afraid of that... Thanks for the help